# Need assistance in extract field in KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

i have a table named ReconDarknetDetectionAlerts_CL which has a field tables_s  with is not parsed properly .It is in json format .Would like to extract 2 new fields Email and Breach Date from the below field in KQL

```
tables_s = [{"headers":["Email","Hash Type","Password Length","Breach Name","Breach Date"],"table_description":"Leaked Credentials Info","values":[["jlacelle@abc.ab","plain",8,"leaked-credentials","2023-07-21 00:00:00"],["pbuma@abc.ab","plain",9,"leaked-credentials","2023-07-21 00:00:00"]]}]
```

Have tried this but its giving me error

```
ReconDarknetDetectionAlerts_CL
| extend emails = extract_all(@"\b([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})\b", 1, tables_s)
| mv-expand email = emails
```

Comment: when you claim "its giving me an error", it would be very helpful if you include as many details as possible about the error, so that readers don't need to guess or make assuptions

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

**`Input table:`**

[image]

**`KQL Query which worked for me:`**

```
let x= datatable (tab : dynamic )
[
 dynamic([{"headers":["Email","Hash Type","Password Length","Breach Name","Breach Date"],"table_description":"Leaked Credentials Info","values":[["jlacelle@abc.ab","plain",8,"leaked-credentials","2023-07-21 00:00:00"],["pbuma@abc.ab","plain",9,"leaked-credentials","2023-07-21 00:00:00"]]}])
];
x
| mv-expand  tab
| evaluate bag_unpack( tab)
| mv-expand values
| extend Email = values[0], Breach_Date=values[4]
| project Email,Breach_Date
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5VQTUvDQBC951cMc2ohkVgFNVIQP0ChiAdvIZTJ7tik3WyWZFtT1P/uJG2p4kl2Yfe9mXkzbwx76KagycvJDcNIHkhAby1VpYJxkAYHMEo/sGDS3LSYpPhQUWkwxEdqC3jdOpb/C7Xte91omLFd+EKY24ZJFfBMFR/RPXnGLMSh5Vxzq5rS+bK2mOCMacUa7hrWbH1JpoUn+1ZL8YbMmvvWKS4NKTaGbyhXJ5RL0BkqLYaXIZpBIFJHAQlP4slZFF9Ek1OI42S4MkCKLl9X9Efl6j8q2Vc2DrLroAs+odpE3DmyGkC8CcH90OIWclrM19aRWo360PhX8s5Zn955FjysFqZ7Po2zEHabm/ebm+7p80wqXFMvWfldSfgj6xuvTtBH2gEAAA==)